# Retrieving Data from Firebase Database in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know there are some similar questions about the Firebase Database, but I couldn't find the right solution. Sorry about that.

I created a tableview in my ViewController.swift file. What I wanted to do is getting data from Firebase Database and put them into the tableview cells one by one. At each tableview cell, there is only a textview, which i wanted to make it equal to the sentences' values from database. However, there is a problem at getting the data from database. I think that problem is at the snapshot part (in the following code), because i added the print("SNAP: (snap)") function in order to check whether it works or not, but it doesn't even print.

Here is my viewDidLoad function in the ViewController.swift file:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    DataService.dataService.REF_SENTENCES.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, 
withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.sentences = []
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                print("SNAP: \(snap)")
                if let sentenceDictionary = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let sentence = Sentence(sentenceKey: key, dictionary: sentenceDictionary)
                    self.sentences.append(sentence)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

And here the DataService.swift file for Firebase Database:

Reminder: Actual URL for my project is different. This one is just an example.

```
let URL_BASE = "https://example-project.firebaseio.com"
class DataService {
static let dataService = DataService()

private var _REF_BASE = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(URL_BASE)
private var _REF_SENTENCES = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("\(URL_BASE)/sentences")

var REF_BASE: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return _REF_BASE
}

var REF_SENTENCES: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return _REF_SENTENCES
}
```

}

And here is the Firebase Database: [Firebase Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Hjt.png)

**UPDATE:**
Because Firebase SDK has upgraded, some of the functions are called in a different way in new Firebase. The reason why i got problem on getting the data from database is because i just used some old version Firebase codes in my project.

Comment: Are you still using legacy Firebase or have you upgraded to the new Firebase?

Comment: I've created this project yesterday and installed latest version of Firebase. @chickenparm

Comment: Some of your code is from the old Firebase and does not work with the new Firebase. One example is you no longer use the URL in the format you have. I recommend reading the iOS migration guide here https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#get_a_database_reference_numbered

Comment: Actually I got help from a swift tutorial. After the tutorial, i've read the latest documentation of Firebase and i changed some of the codes. However, after i changed it, i thought that it is okay now for new Firebase. Thanks a lot, i am going to read it now. @chickenparm